# Laravel Vue Stucked when trying to run npm run dev on aws ec2 ubuntu

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, vue.js, ubuntu

I upload my laravel vue project on ec2 ubuntu server all commands is running on local server and project is also running on local with no errors but on ubuntu server when try to run npm run dev it stucked on 22% .... you can see it in the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe because of lack of resources. If you are using the free tier then it is most likely your VPS has 1 GB of ram and other limited resources. npm run dev does a lot of work under the hood. And when it lacks resources, it tends to freeze. Try building tour app on local for production and then deploy on ec2 using a web server.